# How get object and operation from AWS access denied exception in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-access-policy

Any aws service can throw AcceeDenied Exception. Which is logged like that:

```
somePromise.catch((err) => {
    console.error(`Failed to store logs into CloudWatch`, err);
    callback(err);
})
```

Cloud watch logs show:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Access Denied",
    "errorType": "AccessDenied",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:577:35)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)",
        "Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
        "Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
        "Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
        "Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)"
    ]
}
```

First of all where is a stack trace? :)

Second is there a way to deternime what resource and operation were requested? (There are several chained promises and it is unclear what is wrong)

Comment: isn't the stacktrace the array you recieved? the operation and the resource may be on the headers, check a look ;)

Comment: Stack trace come from `node_modelus` folders as you can see. It is not "my code"

Answer (score 0):

You're unlikely to get much more detail out of the JavaScript Stacktrace from my experience. A more helpful route I've found is to look at what AWS services the libraries that I'm using (and getting `somePromise` from) are accessing.

One other way that you could possibly glean some of this information is from the AWS side, using **CloudTrail** and **CloudWatch Logs**. You would first need to [create a CloudTrail in your AWS Account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-a-trail-using-the-console-first-time.html). Next you would need to [send CloudTrail events to CloudWatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/send-cloudtrail-events-to-cloudwatch-logs.html).

Once you have your CloudTrail events going to CloudWatch Logs, you can use CloudWatch Logs to query for "Access Denied" and "Unauthorized Operation" messages. To do this, go to **CloudWatch** in the AWS Console, and go to the **Logs** Section. Next look for your CloudTrail Log group. Normally the Default log group is called `CloudTrail/Default`. Once you go into that log Group, Press the **Search Logs** button at the top. This will bring up all of the logs in the Logs Streams for this Log Group. You can then enter a query that will get only the **Access Denied** and **Unauthorized operation** events. To do this, enter the query `{ ($.errorCode = "*UnauthorizedOperation") || ($.errorCode = "AccessDenied*") }`

I found this to be onerous, and very time consuming, so I wrote a [utility to send these Access Denied and Unauthorized Operation messages to Slack](https://github.com/Giftbit/activity-aware-ids-aws/blob/master/infrastructure/cloudformation.yaml) for me Automatically. You can check it out at https://github.com/Giftbit/activity-aware-ids-aws/blob/master/infrastructure/cloudformation.yaml. It also includes a helpful CloudFormation template to stand this up for you, provided that you have already created your CloudTrail and have the events sent to CloudWatch Logs.